# Confused about Random Variables question.

Tags: probability

The question is as follows:

"Let Y be a random variable with values 1,2,3. If P(Y = 1) = .3, P(Y = 2) = A, what is P(Y = 3)? What is P(Y >= 2)?"

I understand the concept of random variables but I'm not sure why I cannot figure out how to use A, why is an A there?

I am not given a probability function of A or anything that has to do with that variable.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Looks like it's just meant to be an unknown quantity.

Comment: So should i just assume P(Y=3) = 1 - (.3 + A) ? @Null

Comment: @AlecLeonK Yes, that's the best you can do with that sparse information.

Comment: Alright thank you @GDumphart

Answer (score 0):

$P(3) = \neg P(1) \wedge \neg P(2) = 1 - (P(1)+P(2)) = 1 - 0.3 - A = 0.7 - A$.